# Button that performs changes to a record in a database (HTML TABLE)

Tags: php, html-table

I'm creating an inventory web app for my high school library.
All the pages are built in HTML, and PHP communicates with the MySQL database.

One of the pages of the app allows you to search by title of the book in the database and returns the result in one table (or more tables if there are more than one results).

I want to add a button inside a cell of the table that, when clicked, performs a change to a parameter of the record.
More precisely, one of the column header is called "availability". If the answer is "y", then the book is available. When the user is selling the book, clicks the Sell button on the right that changes the parameter to "n".

See the screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15y4w6UZpWVIVZjsQN6H3fsmTQeTdFDmP/view?usp=sharing

How can I do that?

This is the code of the table:

```
    echo '<table style="width:100%" border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Author:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Title:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>ISBN:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Cover Price:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>40% Price:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Availability:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Returned:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Phone:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>First Name:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Last Name:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Class:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Student ID:</p></center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="navy" face="Helvetica" size="3"><center><p>Sell:</p></center></font><th>';

    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['author'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['title'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['isbn'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['coverprice'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['fortyprice'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['availability'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['returned'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['phone'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['firstname'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['lastname'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['class'].'</center></font><th>';
    echo '<th><font color="black" face="Helvetica" size="2"><center>'.$results['studentid'].'</center></font><th>';
            echo '<th><form action="BOOKS_changestatus.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" value="Sell"></th>';





    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<br>';



                }
```

The changestatus.php file is still empty tho...

Comment: You didn't close `form` tag

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. Fixed in my code. However, can you help me figure it out?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what to figure out

Comment: Again: close your `<form>`, remove `<br>`, add `</table>`.

Comment: What is the purpose of `changestatus.php`

Comment: Change the "availability" data of that row from "y" to "n" in the database

Answer (score 0):

You did a little bit mistake there. You must have to put a hidden field inside your form and send it to php page where you want to update it in your database
Reaplace this

```
echo '<th><form action="BOOKS_changestatus.php" method="GET"><input type="submit" value="Sell"></th>';
```

with this

```
echo '<th><form action="changestatus.php" method="GET">// I assumed that changestatus.php is your php page where you want to do database work
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' .$results['studentid'] . '"> //I assume that this is your id in your database
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sell"></form></th>';
```

Now in `changestatus.php` page

```
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
 {
   $id = $_GET['studentid'];

   //Now you have id and it will be easy for you now to update record in your database against this id

 }
```

**Note:**  I have made some assumptions regarding your code. You can correct me if there is anything wrong

Comment: I fixed the table alignment. In the change status page what do I have to add? The Sell button should change the "availability" parameter in the database from "y" to "n".

Comment: Hi, have you made form like in my answer?

Comment: Actually, I decided to use a link instead of a button, as you can see in this screenshot. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z54C-DAjg72HnehLbthaL46ryLNNI7SC/view?usp=sharing The link redirects to the changestatus.php that should perform the change

Comment: You can treat form submit button as your normal button with a hidden field of `studentid`.and then in `changestatus.php` you can get `studentid` by `$_GET` request

Comment: I have updated the answer to make it easy for you to understand and also check again `changestatus.php` file

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Why should I use a hidden field? As you can see, "Sell" is just a link and links to changestatus.php. I have a primary key that auto increments for every new database record.

Comment: Ok, Let's clarify first. How will you get to know that which record you have to update?

Comment: This is the main problem. I have a unique ID for every database record..

Comment: That is what I am saying. You should embed id of each record into hidden field and send it to `changestatus.php` page through `$_GET` request

Comment: Ooh right! Now I understand! However I can see that you used the button input. What if I decided to use the link method <a href="https://www.myurl.com/BOOKS_changestatus.php?">Sell</a>

Comment: Yes, You can also do that in this way `<a href="myurl.com/BOOKS_changestatus.php?studentid=$results['studentid']">Sell</a>;`

Comment: And in `changestatus.php` change `if(isset($_GET[submit'']))` to `if(isset($_GET[studentid'']))`